# Tomcat configuration for static files

Tags: tomcat, static

Hello i have read the whole days long possibilities to map a upload folder to tomcat.

What i did:

1. create a file /conf/Catalina/localhost/test.xml

Content of the file:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <context docbase="/home/uploads"></context>
```

1. Start tomcat
2. I get the following error: Schwerwiegend: Error deploying configuration descriptor test.xml

What is wrong?

My folder uploads contains a file 4.png so that i thought i should be able to open that file with
localhost:8080/test/4.png after the context file could be read.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: nobody who can asnwer tzhis question? Perhaps the euopeion championship is the reason :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<context>` (sic) is invalid: it needs to be `<Context>` (note the leading capital letter). Also, the `docbase` attribute should be `docBase` (note the difference in case).

You are better-off upgrading to Tomcat 7 and using "aliases" than deploying a do-nothing context -- especially one that allows anyone to upload files that can change the behavior of the server.